# Will a question ban lift be delayed by opening bounties?

Tags: support, bounty, post-ban

I was going through my old questions and noticed this one: [Scrollbars appearing for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33964543/5221346). I realised that even though there is a post that answers it partially and does provide a solution (my own answer), I have absolutely no clue why that workaround actually worked. I am curious to understand what is going on, so I edited the question to clarify and remove unnecessary information in hopes of attracting the attention of someone who can answer it.

Alas, it did not get any attention, so I thought perhaps raising a bounty is a good idea. However, I have been question banned for several months and despite my intense daily grinding, I have not even managed to reach 1k rep (life is tough when all you can do is to answer basic Java and HTML questions).

If the act of awarding a bounty (minimum 100 rep in this case) will set me back 100 rep worth of "positive contributions", it will be out of the question - even though I really would like an answer to that question. So my question is this:

*If I open a bounty on a question, will it take me longer to get out of the question ban?*

Comment: You need to be careful that any 'exported' bounty rep is not seen as asset-stripping in favour of an unbanned puppet account.

Comment: As always, the key to getting out of a question ban is to improve your existing questions.

Comment: @Shog9 If only that was possible. Ah, how wonderful life would be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question ban doesn't look at your rep, it looks at your contributions and the feedback given to them.  Posting a bounty changes your rep, but it doesn't change your contributions or the feedback given to them.

Comment: In that case, do reviews count as contributions?

Comment: @Gendarme The specifics of the algorithm are not public.

Comment: So potentially starting a bounty *might* help, in increasing feedback on your existing question. *Might*.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Or it could hurt.

Comment: @Servy Very true. It's like a sword with an unknown number of edges.

Comment: Since there are three possible feedback outcomes -- gain, loss, or no change -- perhaps it is a [three edged sword](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/139949-understanding-is-a-three-edged-sword-your-side-their-side).

Comment: It's the Sword of Shog, sorta like the sword of Damocles but, instead of hanging over you, you have to sit on it.